# MongoDB REST API dynamic data pagination

Tags: mongodb, rest, express, mongoose

I am implementing REST API with Express and Mongoose. I am stuck with a task to paginate results for a collection with large number of documents. Document is a social media post which has fields like: *created_at*, *updated_at* and *score*.

Ordinary paging implementation using limit and page number doesn't work because the nature of data. Posts can be removed or added while user is browsing the results.

I could implement range-based pagination as suggested in MongoDB documentation.
Last items in a page *created_at* value could be used to query next page.

```
Post.find({ created_at: { $gt: req.query.next } })
```

But what if I want to sort results by *score* which is not unique or all scores are the same?

Comment: Mongo `cursor.sort()` can sort based on more than 1 field

Comment: For exaple I gave in a question. I can't find key combination to make it work. Sort by created_at and score makes no difference.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mongodb-user/paging%7Csort:relevance/mongodb-user/_Jrv9vI1lDE/Wg0eGV2AkZYJ

I just found the same topic in google groups with perfect answer.

> You could try creating a compound index on age and _id, and sort by both fields to get the first three documents.  To get the subsequent set of users, your query should return documents that satisfy either of the following requirements:
>
> - have the same age as the last document and have a greater _id
>   or
> - have a greater age

> For example (lastAge and lastID are the age and _id of the latest user):

> `db.collection.find( { $or : [ { age : lastAge, _id : {$gt : lastID } } , { age : {$gt : lastID } } ] } )`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this, but in your case i would suggest to create the find / sort conditions dynamicly and use them in your find statement.

Outta my head just to give you an idea:

```
var MyFilter = {};
var MySort = {};
if (req.query.created_at != undefined) {
    MyFilter = { created_at : { $gte : req.query.created_at) } };
}

if (req.query.sortOn != undefined){
    MySort = { req.query.sort : 1 };
}

Post.find(MyFilter)
.sort(MySort)
.exec(function (err, posts) {
    ===do your stuff===
});
```